# Asking about ettiquette for confusing exam questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

[This question on the Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26192/need-help-with-a-set-associative-cache-memory-problem) involves an example exam question which is very unclear. I was wondering if it would be on-topic (including not "bad subjective") here to ask what a student should do when faced with such questions in an exam (or homework).

(A related question might be how to *grade* such questions. Knowing how an answer to a seemingly unclear question will be graded may give hints at how such should be answered.)

If it is on-topic, what tags should be used. (I am guessing [etiquette](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) and [exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) would be appropriate.)

---

The poster of the question on CS.SE is in an awful position: the professor 'is known for [possessive pronoun extracted] "unclear" questions'.

Answer (score 3):

I think both

> what a student should do when faced with such questions in an exam (or homework)

and

> how to grade such questions

are reasonable questions. The latter would obviously relate to learning that the question was ambiguous after giving the exam.

You will probably need some type of example to narrow down the issue since there is a difference between a question without all the information needed to answer and a question that has multiple correct answers. You can use the link question, but you will want to explain the issues so no CS people can understand.

As for tags [exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) and [etiquette](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) seem reasonable for the first question and [exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exams) and [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading) for the second question.